# Trying to add a sum of first consecutive odd squares?

Tags: java, loops, sum

I'm trying to add a sum of consecutive odd squares to add up to the same number. For example: the first 4 consecutive odd square numbers added together will equal 84, (1*1) + (3*3) + (5*5) + (7*7) = 84. The  Attached is my code. Result 2, the non-loop code, is correct. I need help on resolving what I'm doing wrong with result1's loop code.

Inputnumber equals the number of odd squares requested.

```
public static int sumWithLoop (int inputNumber) 
{
    int result1 = 0;
    int counter = 1;

    while (counter <= inputNumber)
    {
        result1 = result1*result1 + counter;
        counter = counter + 2;
    }
    return result1;
}
public static int sumWithoutLoop (int inputNumber)
{

    int result2 = (inputNumber*(2 * inputNumber - 1) * (2 * inputNumber + 1) / 3);
    return result2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant `result1 = result1 + counter * counter;` instead of `result1 = result1*result1 + counter;`.

Comment: I've tried the code. Input 4 ---> Result 1 = 10, and Result 2 = 84.

Comment: @TSD302 What is `inputNumber`? Using values from your example, is it `4` (number of odd squares to add), `7` (max. odd number to square), or `84` (number to achieve)? Your code, with the fix from this answer, is assuming `inputNumber` is `7` (or `8`), because you're comparing to the odd-valued `counter` variable.

Comment: InputNumber is the requested number of oddsquares. In this example, I'm trying to do number of odd squares to add, which is 4. The number I'm trying to achieve is 84. In another example. I would input 7 odd squared numbers, and the result would be 455.

Answer (score 0):

Most of your problem is in the math inside the `while` loop.

1. `result1` should be initialized to 1.  (At least the way I'm doing it.)
2. Your first line in the block squares `result1` and adds `counter` to it.  What you need is something more like this:

   ```
   result1 = result1 + (int) (Math.pow(1 + 2 * counter, 2));
   ```

   This takes `result1` and adds the next odd square to it. (`1 + 2 * counter` = the next odd number)
3. With the above code to determine the next odd number, `counter` should be incremented by **1** at the end of the `while` loop, rather than 2 (because I multiply `counter` by 2 in the `Math.pow` function).

My final code looks like this:

```
public static int sumWithLoop (int inputNumber) 
{
    int result1 = 1;
    int counter = 1;

    while (counter < inputNumber)
    {
        result1 = result1 + (int) (Math.pow(1 + 2 * counter, 2));
        counter = counter + 1;
    }
    return result1;
}
```

It returns 84 when `inputNumber` is 4, 165 when it's 5, 286 when it's 6, etc., so it looks like it works.
Hope this helped!

---

P.S.  Just FYI, I/you could have used `result1 += (int) (Math.pow(1 + 2 * counter, 2));` in the first line in the while loop.  The difference is the **+=** operator, which adds the following value to the preceding variable.  It's more concise than `this = this + somethingMore;`

Also, in the second line, we could've used `counter++;`, instead of `counter = counter + 1;`  **++** adds one to the variable it's used on.